# Android SDK downgrade How to

Tags: android

i have Android SDK 4.0.3 installed , i want to install a precedent version (2.2 for example) so should i uninstall the 4.0.3 version or not?

How to do it ?

Comment: You want to use android 2.2 and you don't know which SDK to use, is that your question?

Comment: When you install android SDK (for example, to use it with Eclipse) then you are able to choose which android version (starting from 1.5) you want when creating a new android project, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install needed SDK in Android SDK manager
http://developer.android.com/sdk/adding-components.html

And then simply choose needed SDK in eclipse when create a new project, or change SDK in "Android" tab of project preferences in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not downgrade.

Here's how it works: Android SDK consists of several components. One is SDK tools, which are common between platform versions and should be only upgraded. Those are host system tools (they work on your workstation), like Emulator, android (aka Android SDK manager), adb (aka Android Debug Bridge), build tools etc. Additionally, you need to install one or more platform SDK. Platform SDK is mostly a collection of jars specific for selected Android version (mind that internally API level is used), so you can compile your code against it. Several versions can be installed at the same time. You should use 'android' tool to install selected android SDK platform.

When you write Android application, you specify minimum API level (minimal version of Android, on which application will be working), and target API level, which is a version of Android you compile against (so no newer API will be used here). You can set minimum API level without having installed SDK with that level, but you need to have installed platform SDK with target API level prior to building.